# How to queue clients and serve them one at a time without using any threads?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a socket programming application that gives returns the evaluation of a math expression to the client based on input from the client to the server. It should serve which means if there is a client being served and another client want to connect it should be queued. After the client is done (types quit) it pick up the next client and serve them. I'm really stuck on trying to serve the other client as when the first client is done the connection just resets and the second client is never severed.

From what I've seen the second client is connected and is in the backlog (goes to 50 by default) so I'm trying to find out how I can pick up and serve that client. I've pasted part of the server code which I believe is the culprit. I'm avoiding using threads entirely for this task.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPMathServerPersistent {
    private static int PORT = 5000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);                                         
            System.out.println("This is the TCP Server.");

            while (true) {
                Socket connectionSocket = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Client accepted.");
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

                while (true) {
                    String line = in.readUTF();
                    String newLine = Double.toString(eval(line));
                    out.writeUTF(newLine);
                    out.flush();  // flushed the output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out (done to improve performance)
                }   
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {                                         
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use threads?

Comment: I'm not allowed to for this assignment.

Comment: You need to close the accepted socket, or its input stream, or best of all its output stream, when you're finished with it, and you also need to *not* ignore `IOExceptions`. You would also be well advised to catch `EOFException` inside the loop and use it as another signal to close the socket and break out of the read  loop. You can't rely on the client always sending the `quit`, and in fact you don't need to.

Comment: NB the `flush()` is redundant here (although not aways). If you're getting a 'connection reset' at `in.readUTF()` as per your comment to @Patrick's incorrect answer, there is something wrong with your client. Is it using `writeUTF()`? is it reading the reply? with `readUTF()`? and is it closing the socket correctly?

Comment: @user207421 How would use the catch block to close the socket? In my code the socket isn't the scope where I can do so? Doing catch(IOException e){ server.close() will result in an unresolved variable?

Answer (score -1):

I would not use the second while loop. Does not seem like you need it and as it says while(true) the loop does not stop and the other loop cant go on, so the other client cant be accepted

Comment: It looks removing this loop causes my code to accept only one line of input. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot completely remove the inner loop, but you need to make sure it terminates. You write yourself in the explanation when it should terminate. Make that the condition in the loop.

Comment: @Robert I've tried to add a condition but I still can't pick up second client after the first is done as I get a connection reset.                                                         String line = in.readUTF();
String closeword = "quit";
                while (!line.equals(closeword)) {
 String newLine = Double.toString(eval(line));            
                    out.writeUTF(newLine);
                    out.flush();  
                    line = in.readUTF();}    }